# How to Restrict the anonymous domain accessing my webisite

Tags: azure

! I have implemented a WebApp and SQL-DB.
  added custom domain and SSL certificates (which bought at CA).

for SSL offloading purpose we configured an azure application gateway.
with all setup.

next, we configured azure traffic manager so that traffic manager decide active web app routing.

our concern is when I adding the CNAME record for traffic manager in GoDaddy it is routing to WebApp, everything is great.

but when I search "xxxx.com" Digwebinterface  it shows all connections to WebApp

in this, I took the traffic manager CNAME record and added to another domain then the duplicate domain also accessing all my content of the website and even create a record in SQL also.

in this scenario I losing my website restriction unauthorized domain can map site

any suggestion and insights it would be grateful to

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is to create a filter in your code for inspecting the host of headers of request to allow or deny the accessing from different domain.

Here is my sample code in Node.js with `express`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const allowedHosts = [`localhost:${port}`]

var domainFilter = function(req, res, next) {
    if(allowedHosts.includes(req.headers.host)) {
        next()
    } else {
        res.status(403).end()
    }
}

app.use(domainFilter)

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

It will allow the request from `localhost:3000` and deny the request from `127.0.0.1:3000` or others, as the figures below.

Fig 1. Allow the request from `localhost:3000`

[image]

Fig 2. Deny from `127.0.0.1:3000` or others

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. will implement and update you back.

Comment: thanks dear it works fine instead of localhost is there any option for domain URL